# Handling SD Storage / Compatibility

Tags: android, storage, compatibility

In one of my games I'll try to access the SD Card by calling `getExternalFilesDir`.

As you know - this method is not available at Android 2.1 devices (level 7 api). I cannot switch back to an older API because of `admob` (which needs level 13 api).

Therefore I also cannot use older functions like `getExternalStorageDir` - because that is simply not available on api level 13.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your question - you want to access the SD Card on Android 2.1 and above (API 7 ... API 13)? You want it to do it with a single source? You cannot because neither getExternalFilesDir and gexternalStorageDir are available at all API versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acces SD-Card use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get path of sd-card. This method is applicable for all api levels as it is incorporated in android since API level 1.

You can get the storage directory for your application's files by doing this.

```
String externalFileDirectory =  
          Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
externalFileDirectory += "/Android/data/your.application.package/.files/"
```

Note that files in `externalFileDirectory` will be automatically deleted when your-application will be uninstalled.

[Admob help](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#requirements) says in Requirements section that Admob requires Android 1.5(API 3) or greater. So you can set your `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="api_level" />` minsdkversion lower than 13 and can use `getExternalFilesDir`. And hence you can use `getExternalFilesDir` method.

Fory Admob you only have to set target in default.properties or project.properties to 13. Write `target=android-13` in your default.properties or project.properties file. Your app will still support your application's minSdkVersion.

Comment: You are great, maybe google should post that into their help section about data storage.

I had setup the admob thing right, but I want to use latest sdk api, just need a fallback for api level 7 for using sd card - you pointed me the right way, thank you

is there any reason why you write ".files" with a dot in front?